# Error : Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Offset not contained in string - can not find solution

Tags: php

I know, this question has been asked, but unfortunately, there are no answers how to solve this problem.

This appears in my logfiles:

**PHP message: PHP Warning:  strpos(): Offset not contained in string in ... on line 479**

Unfortunately, I can not understand what causes this problem and how to fix it. I tested this function many times (with large $text, with short $text, with $spam words and without $spam words) but I never get this error. So, what kind of texts my users submit that cause this error?

```
    if (strposab($text, $spam, 1)) {
    echo "Email addresses and URLs not allowed here";
die;
    }

$spam = array('http','www','hotmail','yahoo','gmail','msn');


function strposab($haystack, $needles=array(), $offset=0) {
$chr = array();
foreach($needles as $needle) {
$res = strpos($haystack, $needle, $offset);
if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
}
if(empty($chr)) return false;
return min($chr);
}
```

**Second question:**

For some reason this function does not filter the first word of the string.
For example in this string function does not find word "hotmail":

```
$text = 'hotmail test test test test';
```

but in this string it finds word " hotmail":

```
$text = 'test hotmail test test test test';
```

Comment: ["*Also note that string positions start at 0, and not 1.*"](http://us.php.net/strpos#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues). You're passing `1` instead of `0` as the starting offset, and your users are submitting an empty string/single character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To the first question:**

Most likely at one point you're passing an empty string to your function. `Offset` in the `strpos` call indicates from which character it should start searching for `$needle`. It's 0-based, so if you want to start from the absolute beginning, you either set it to 0 or omit it (it defaults to 0.)

**To the second question:**

As mentioned before, the offset is 0-based, so if `$needle` you're searching for is exactly in the beginning of `$haystack`, it cannot be found if `$offset` is 1. With `$offset = 1` it would be as if you're searching in a string that looks like this: `'otmail test test test test'`.

**One more thing:**

I suggest you should use `stripos`, not `strpos` for your purposes, as it is case-insensitive and will also find words with uppercase letters, if it's something you might need.

Comment: Yes, it was an empty string. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The offset value is higher than the length of the string to search in.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your second question - you have two issues in your code. Assuming your text string is:

```
$text = 'hotmail test test test test';
```

..and your if statement is

```
if (strposab($text, $spam, 1))
```

First, you're starting at offset 1, while the word "hotmail" is at position 0. So by specifying an offset of 1, you're checking against the String:

```
otmail test test test test
```

...and not

```
hotmail test test test test
```

Second of all, with "hotmail" being at position 0, your strposab() function will return a value of int(0), which is a non-Boolean value that when used in a Boolean expression evaluates to FALSE. Therefore, you need to use the !== operator in order to avoid type juggling. So the correct if statement to use will be:

```
if (strposab($text, $spam, 0) !== false)
```