# Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a "read more" script, and i'm having this warning:

> Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in

This warning only appears when the initial description wants to show a certain number of letters, but the full description is smaller.

I'm doing this script using an hidden div, and when the button "read more" is clicked, it toggles the divs

This is the code from the initial description, that only shows some words.

```
<div class="listdescription">
<br><?= strip_tags(substr($key['description'] ,0, strpos($key['description'], ' ', 90))) ?><br><
/div>
```

And this is the full description

```
<div class="teste"><?= $key['description'] ?></div>
```

And the read more link

```
<a class="readmore">read more</a>


<style>
.teste{
display:none;           
}
</style>
```

When the read more is clicked:

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
$('.readmore').click(function(){
$(this).parent().find('.teste').toggle();
$(this).parent().find('.listdescription').toggle();

});
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error : Warning: strpos() \[function.strpos\]: Offset not contained in string - can not find solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251501/error-warning-strpos-function-strpos-offset-not-contained-in-string-ca)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to check that the string is longer that the offset you're looking for:

```
strlen($key['description']) > 90 ? substr($key['description'] ,0, strpos($key['description'], ' ', 90)) : $key['description']
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation comments](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#93816):

> This function raises a warning if the offset is not between 0 and the length of string:
>
> `Warning: strpos(): Offset not contained in string in ...`

In this specific scenario, it's because `$key['description']` is shorter than 90 characters.