# Why is the substr treating alpha numeric column value as string

Tags: php, substr

Not sure why I would be getting the following warning, giving the that data being used in this row column is alpha-numeric.

[20-Jan-2023 10:13:10 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  strpos(): Offset not contained in string in /www/zendphp74/htdocs/IP Lookup/getIPAddress on line 345

```
$str = strval($row[TIME_IN_IP_ADDRESS]);

$timeInIP = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '.', strpos($str, '.')+1));

if ($timeInIP === '10.390'){
                              return 'USA';
                           }
```

Comment: what is `TIME_IN_IP_ADDRESS`? `$row` are usually call from database. and `TIME_IN_IP_ADDRESS` are similar to define. Please explain this. my english is not good. sory :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : Warning: strpos() \[function.strpos\]: Offset not contained in string - can not find solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251501/error-warning-strpos-function-strpos-offset-not-contained-in-string-ca)

Comment: ramin - $row[TIME_IN_IP_ADDRESS] is from the SQL call from DB2 table.  Define as alpha-numeric

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode()` function instead of `strpos()` function to break the IP address into an array then you can add checks.

*Use the following code.*

```
$ipArr = explode(".", $row[TIME_IN_IP_ADDRESS]);

$timeInIP = $ipArr[0] . "." . $ipArr[1];
if ($timeInIP === "10.390") {
  return "USA";
}
```